# docker-compose up doesn't map ports on centos 7

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos

I'm trying to docker-compose an existing application. Now I struggle on centos on a basic task.

**Given docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
          - "1024:80"
```

When run with `docker-compose up` localhost:1024 is **not** accessible. When I add the started container to the default bridge network (`docker network connect <id of bridge> <id of container>`), localhost:1024 **is** accessible.

When run with `docker run -p 1024:80 nginx:latest` localhost:1024 **is** accessible.

- docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31
- Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810

When attempting to docker-compose up the same file on macOS localhost:1024 **is** accessible.

**EDIT #1**

`docker ps` PORTS output: 0.0.0.0:1024->80/tcp

new interface added `ifconfig`: br-da0abb61196d

Same behavior on different ports e.g. 8080

Comment: Is there anything in the container logs when you try to access the container? Does `docker ps` show the port mapping after you have used `docker-compose`? Also, does it work if you try it on another port, say, 8080?